# If $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $f\in C^1([-1,1])$ and $f(-1)=f(1)$, then can $f$ be expanded into Fourier series?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

If $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $f\in C^1([-1,1])$ and $f(-1)=f(1)$, then can $f$ be expanded into Fourier series ?

I know the fact that

---

if $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is periodic with period $T=2L$, continuous, and piecewise $C^1$ function (i.e., for arbitrary interval $[a,b]$, $g|_{[a,b]}$ is piecewise $C^1$), then for all $x\in [-L,L]$, $g$ can be Fourier expandable at $x$.

---

Let $\tilde{f}:\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ be the extension of $f$. I want to check $\tilde f$ satisfies the condition of $g$.

$\tilde f$ has period $2$ and $\tilde f$ is continuous since $f$ is $C^1$ on $(-1,1)$ and $f(-1)=f(1)$.

I don't know whether $\tilde f$ is piecewise $C^1$.

I have to check whether $\tilde f|_{[a,b]}$ is piecewise $C^1$ for arbitrary $[a,b]$.

e.g. if $[a,b]=[0,2]$, then $1$ is in $[a,b]$.
$(\tilde {f}|_{[0,2]})'(1-0)=(\tilde {f}|_{[0,2]})'(1+0)$ doesn't necessarily hold and $(\tilde {f}|_{[0,2]})'$ is not continuous at $1$. I'm worried about this. Even in this case, is $\tilde f|_{[0,2]}$ piecewise $C^1$ ?

Comment: The pieces where to check "piecewise $C^1$" are the intervals $[k-1,k+1]$, for $k\in2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: yes, it can. As far as I remember the Fourier series of functions of bounded variation converges pointwise to the function, and if $f\in C^1$ then it is of bounded variation

Comment: @owl Is that the definition of "piecewise $C^1$" ? Do you have any reference ?